# gemspec error on creating new rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rails-engines

I am trying to create rails engine using the below link:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

I have received below errors

> You have one or more invalid gemspecs that need to be fixed.
>       The gemspec at /home/shariq/Documents/plugin/blorgh/blorgh.gemspec is not valid. Please fix this gemspec.

The validation error was `'"FIXME" or "TODO" is not a description'`

I already tried bundle update and bundle install

Here is all myworking

log

```
shariq@SDEV-MACHINE:~/Documents/plugin$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
shariq@SDEV-MACHINE:~/Documents/plugin$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.0.1
shariq@SDEV-MACHINE:~/Documents/plugin$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.15, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
shariq@SDEV-MACHINE:~/Documents/plugin$ rails plugin new blorgh --mountable -d mysql
      create  
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  blorgh.gemspec
      create  MIT-LICENSE
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/controllers/blorgh/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/blorgh/application_helper.rb
      create  app/jobs/blorgh/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/blorgh/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/blorgh/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/blorgh/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/blorgh
      create  app/assets/images/blorgh/.keep
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  lib/blorgh.rb
      create  lib/tasks/blorgh_tasks.rake
      create  lib/blorgh/version.rb
      create  lib/blorgh/engine.rb
      create  app/assets/config/blorgh_manifest.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/blorgh/application.css
      create  app/assets/javascripts/blorgh/application.js
      create  bin/rails
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  test/blorgh_test.rb
      append  Rakefile
      create  test/integration/navigation_test.rb
  vendor_app  test/dummy
         run  bundle install
You have one or more invalid gemspecs that need to be fixed.
The gemspec at /home/shariq/Documents/plugin/blorgh/blorgh.gemspec is not valid. Please fix this gemspec.
The validation error was '"FIXME" or "TODO" is not a description'
shariq@SDEV-MACHINE:~/Documents/plugin$
```

here is gemspec file:

```
##### log #######
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)


require "blorgh/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = "blorgh"
  s.version     = Blorgh::VERSION
  s.authors     = ["Shariq"]
  s.email       = ["gr8shariq@live.com"]
  s.homepage    = "TODO"
  s.summary     = "TODO: Summary of Blorgh."
  s.description = "TODO: Description of Blorgh."
  s.license     = "MIT"

  s.files = Dir["{app,config,db,lib}/**/*", "MIT-LICENSE", "Rakefile", "README.md"]

  s.add_dependency "rails", "~> 5.0.0", ">= 5.0.0.1"

end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory. You have to replace the "TODO" strings in the gemspec with some "actual" descriptions.

Comment: my problem soved thanks. but on creating every engine it is require to modification? or is there anyway to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

There is an already closed issue `#26474` in rails repository:
[`rails plugin new` does not complete properly since bundler 1.12](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26474)

*Ruby on Rails* team member **vipulnsward** said:

> We don't bundle install now - [fbd1e98](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/fbd1e98cf983572ca9884f17f933ffe92833632a)

`fbd1e98`'s commit message explains:

> #### Do not run `bundle install` when generating a new plugin.
>
> Since bundler 1.12.0, the gemspec is validated so the `bundle install`
>   command will fail just after the gem is created causing confusion to the
>   users. This change was a bug fix to correctly validate gemspecs.

Add an option `-B` to skip `bundle install`:

```
rails plugin new NAME -B
```

If you need to run the bundler, you can remove every occurrence of `TODO` and `FIXME` from your `.gemspec` file and then run `bundle install`.

Answer (score 2):

I met the issue today. Here is what I did(git diff) make me survive.

```rb
@@ -9,15 +9,15 @@ Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
   spec.version     = Blorgh::VERSION
   spec.authors     = ["Torvalds Du"]
   spec.email       = ["torvalds@ekohe.com"]
-  spec.homepage    = "TODO"
-  spec.summary     = "TODO: Summary of Blorgh."
-  spec.description = "TODO: Description of Blorgh."
+  spec.homepage    = ""
+  spec.summary     = "Summary of Blorgh."
+  spec.description = "Description of Blorgh."
   spec.license     = "MIT"

   # Prevent pushing this gem to RubyGems.org. To allow pushes either set the 'allowed_push_host'
   # to allow pushing to a single host or delete this section to allow pushing to any host.
   if spec.respond_to?(:metadata)
-    spec.metadata["allowed_push_host"] = "TODO: Set to 'http://mygemserver.com'"
+    spec.metadata["allowed_push_host"] = "http://mygemserver.com"
   else
     raise "RubyGems 2.0 or newer is required to protect against " \
       "public gem pushes."
```

therefore, you have to remove all the text `TODO` from `gem_name.gemspec`.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

***Put this instead.***

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|

  ...

  spec.homepage    = "https://example.com"
  spec.summary     = "Summary of App."
  spec.description = "Description of App."
  
  spec.metadata["allowed_push_host"] = spec.homepage
  spec.metadata["homepage_uri"] = spec.homepage
  spec.metadata["source_code_uri"] = spec.homepage
  spec.metadata["changelog_uri"] = spec.homepage

 ...
end
```